# WPF change Control size when IsExpanded changes

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, controls, datatrigger

I'm trying to set the Height of a RowDefinition in XAML to a smaller value if a Expander changes his IsExpaned Property. Unfortunately it's not working.

Code as following:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
        <RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition.Style>
                <Style TargetType="RowDefinition">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpaned, ElementName=_expFilter}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="140"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </RowDefinition.Style>
        </RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="298*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

May anyone can tell me how to do it correctly? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=_expFilter}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="140"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

You have `IsExpaned`

Comment: Omg - it's always that small little thing that's causing the horrible chaos - Thank you for your answer. Problem solved